# Handle Akka stream's first element specially

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Is there an idiomatic way of handling Akka stream's `Source` first element in a special way? What I have now is:

```
    var firstHandled = false
    source.map { elem =>
      if(!firstHandled) {
        //handle specially
        firstHandled = true
      } else {
        //handle normally
      }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While I would generally go with Ramon's answer, you could also use [`prefixAndTail`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#prefixAndTail), with a prefix of 1, together with [`flatMapConcat`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/stream/stages-overview.html#flatMapConcat) to achieve something similar:

```
val src = Source(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
val fst = Flow[Int].map(i => s"First: $i")
val rst = Flow[Int].map(i => s"Rest:  $i")

val together = src.prefixAndTail(1).flatMapConcat { case (head, tail) =>
  // `head` is a Seq of the prefix elements, which in our case is
  // just the first one. We can convert it to a source of just
  // the first element, processed via our fst flow, and then
  // concatenate `tail`, which is the remainder...
  Source(head).via(fst).concat(tail.via(rst))
}

Await.result(together.runForeach(println), 10.seconds)
// First: 1
// Rest:  2
// Rest:  3
// Rest:  4
// Rest:  5
```

This of course works not just for the first item, but for the first *N* items, with the proviso that those items will be taken up as a strict collection.

Comment: It took me a while to grasp what's really going on. The use of streaming for `fst`  is kind of irrelevant, since `head` is already a `Seq`. At least my use case (CSV files) is one where the 'head' is consumed, used in creation of the processing for 'tail'. I used Akka https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Flow/futureFlow.html#flow-futureflow page but it also had some quirks.. See https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/31284

Answer (score 4):

**Using zipWith**

You could zip the original `Source` with a Source of Booleans that only returns `true` the first time.  This zipped Source can then be processed.

First we'll need a Source that emits the Booleans:

```
//true, false, false, false, ...
def firstTrueIterator() : Iterator[Boolean] = 
  (Iterator single true) ++ (Iterator continually false)

def firstTrueSource : Source[Boolean, _] = 
  Source fromIterator firstTrueIterator
```

We can then define a function that handles the two different cases:

```
type Data = ???
type OutputData = ???

def processData(data : Data, firstRun : Boolean) : OutputData = 
  if(firstRun) { ... }
  else { ... }
```

This function can then be used in a [`zipWith`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Source@zipWith[Out2,Out3](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SourceShape[Out2],_])(combine:(Out,Out2)=%3EOut3):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out3]) of your original Source:

```
val originalSource : Source[Data,_] = ???    

val contingentSource : Source[OutputData,_] =
  originalSource.zipWith(firstTrueSource)(processData)
```

**Using Stateful Flow**

You could create a `Flow` that contains state similar to the example in the question but with a more functional approach:

```
def firstRunner(firstCall : (Data) => OutputData,
                otherCalls : (Data) => OutputData) : (Data) => OutputData = {
  var firstRun = true
  (data : Data) => {
    if(firstRun) {
      firstRun = false
      firstCall(data)
    }
    else
      otherCalls(data)
  }
}//end def firstRunner

def firstRunFlow(firstCall :  (Data) => OutputData, 
                 otherCalls : (Data) => OutputData) : Flow[Data, OutputData, _] = 
  Flow[Data] map firstRunner(firstCall, otherCalls)
```

This Flow can then be applied to your original Source:

```
def firstElementFunc(data : Data) : OutputData = ???
def remainingElsFunc(data : Data) : OutputData = ???

val firstSource : Source[OutputData, _] = 
  originalSource via firstRunFlow(firstElementFunc,remainingElseFunc)
```

**"Idiomatic Way"**

Answering your question directly requires dictating the "idiomatic way".  I answer that part last because it is the least verifiable by the compiler and is therefore closer to opinion.  I would never claim to be a valid classifier of idiomatic code.

My personal experience with akka-streams has been that it is best to switch my perspective to imagining an actual stream (I think of a train with boxcars) of `Data` elements.  Do I need to break it up into multiple fixed size trains?  Do only certain boxcars make it through?  Can I attach another train side-by-side that contains `Boolean` cars which can signal the front?  I would prefer the zipWith method due to my regard of streams (trains).  My initial approach is always to use other stream parts connected together.

Also, I find it best to embed as little code in an akka Stream component as possible.  `firstTrueIterator` and `processData` have no dependency on akka at all.  Concurrently, the `firstTrueSource` and `contingentSource` definitions have virtually no logic.  This allows you to test the logic independent of a clunky ActorSystem and the guts can be used in Futures, or Actors.

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer the approach with zip, one can also use `statefulMapConcat`:

```
source
  .statefulMapConcat { _ =>
        var firstRun = true
        elem => {
          if (firstRun) {
            //first
            firstRun = false
          } else {
            //not first            
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Didn't you mean var instead of val?

Comment: I believe using this condemns one's stream out of parallelism, i.e. no `mapAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prepend` to prepend a source to flows. Just prepend single item source to the flow, after it is drained, rest of the original source will continue.

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/prepend.html

```
 Source(List(1, 2, 3))
  .prepend(Source.single(0))
  .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
```

`0
 1
 2
 3`